# Fatal Error trying to move from GameScene to ViewController with Storyboard ID

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skscene

I've been used the following code with great success going from **Main Menu view (UIViewController)** to the **Game Play (GameViewController.swift - UIViewController)**.

I've also tested **Main Menu view** to **Game Over view (UIViewController)** to make sure that the Game Over view is all hooked up correctly and it works fine but I've tried calling a function from the **GameScene.swift (SKScene)** to **GameViewController.swift** to switch view when the game if over (Game Over view).

But I'm getting a **Fatal Error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Why would I be getting this error from trying to move out of GameScene.swift via GameViewController.swift but not from any other UIViewController like Main Menu or Game Over?

```
func goToGameOver() {
        print("Fetched: goToGameOver()")
        let gameOverController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameOverController") as? GameOverController
        gameOverController!.missionMode = missionMode
        gameOverController!.missionLevel = missionLevel
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameOverController!, animated: true)
    }
```

If you need anymore information to help please let me know.

Thanks for all your help people!

---

**Updated code**

My storyboard is named *Main.storyboard*

I've updated by code based and the answer below and as you can see in the comments I'm no longer receiving any errors but I'm also not seeing a change/switch in the views from my GameScene to GameOverController view.

```
func goToGameOver() {
        print("Fetched: goToGameOver()")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let gameOverController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameOverController") as? GameOverController
        gameOverController!.missionMode = missionMode
        gameOverController!.missionLevel = missionLevel
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameOverController!, animated: true)
    }
```

---

**Update to show storyboard setup.**

Could it be getting not response because my Game Scene Controller (UIViewControllers) entered the SKScene and now the Navigation Controller is broken? It seems odd that I'm not receiving any errors...

[image: This is my pages basic storyboard setup]

Top Left: Navigation Controller

Top Centre: Main Manu Controller

Top Right: Game Scene Controller

Bottom Centre: Game Over Controller

---

**Update providing GameViewController.swift**

Here is my Game View Controller and I haven't assigned the navigationController because I didn't seem to need to do this in my Main Menu Controller or Game Over Controller. How can I go about assigning the navigationController in swift?

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import iAd

class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {

    var iAdBanner = ADBannerView()
    var bannerVisible = false

    var missionMode: Bool!
    var missionLevel: Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = true
            scene.size = skView.bounds.size
            skView.showsNodeCount = true

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

            scene.missionMode = missionMode
            scene.missionLevel = missionLevel

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        iAdBanner.frame = CGRectMake(0, -iAdBanner.frame.height, self.view.frame.width, 0)
        iAdBanner.delegate = self
        bannerVisible = false
    }

    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        if(bannerVisible == false) {

            // Add banner Ad to the view
            if(iAdBanner.superview == nil) {
                self.view.addSubview(iAdBanner)
            }

            // Move banner into visible screen frame:
            UIView.beginAnimations("iAdBannerShow", context: nil)
            banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height)
            banner.alpha = 1
            UIView.commitAnimations()
            bannerVisible = true
        }

    }

    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
        if(bannerVisible == true) {
            // Move banner below screen frame:
            UIView.beginAnimations("iAdBannerHide", context: nil)
            banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -banner.frame.size.height)
            banner.alpha = 0
            UIView.commitAnimations()
            bannerVisible = false
        }

    }

    func goToGameOver() {
        print("Fetched: goToGameOver()")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        print(storyboard)
        let gameOverController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameOverController") as! GameOverController
        gameOverController.missionMode = missionMode
        gameOverController.missionLevel = missionLevel
        print(gameOverController)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameOverController, animated: true)
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return .AllButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .All
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: are you checking to see if your navigationcontroller is not nil,  seems like your last problem was your storyboard was nil.  If this is inside your game scene then that is probably what is happening,  how is navigation controller getting assigned?

Comment: At the moment my navigation controller is assigned to the Main Menu Controller. The first view that gets shown. I'll show a screenshot above of my storyboard setup.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I get the following when printing the  storyboard and gameOverController constant:<UIStoryboard: 0x7fc19a48ada0>
<AppName.GameOverController: 0x7fc19a4bfac0>

Comment: yes, using the current method you would,  can you show me where you are assigning the navigation controller, and how you are creating the scene at all points in your code

Comment: Sorry @Knight0fDragon I added my Game View Controller code to the question. Hope that's what your after to help me out. :D I have a feeling not assigning the navigationController is were my issue is but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: Is your project set up with a navigationController?  If not, then you want to be using self.presentViewController

Comment: using the **self.presentViewController(gameOverController, animated: false, completion: nil)** give me a _Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x108f2d7f0) to 'SKView' (0x1081f7a18)_ error message. Don't worry I think I'll use scenes instead of storyboard for my menus and game over view.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how your storyBoard init but you can specify your storyboard with your project

```
func goToGameOver() {
        print("Fetched: goToGameOver()")
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryBoardName", bundle: nil)
        let gameOverController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameOverController") as? GameOverController
        gameOverController!.missionMode = missionMode
        gameOverController!.missionLevel = missionLevel
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameOverController!, animated: true)
    }
```

should work

Comment: Very strange, I've tried the following and I'm now not getting any errors but I'm also not getting a new view. So my screen it not changing to the GameOverController. would this be because I'm trying to switch views from my GameScene.swift (SKScene) by calling a function from GameViewController.swift (UIViewController). My storyboard name way Main.storyboard. Updated code above.

Comment: Thanks @Özgür I appreciate the help.